# AngularJS is giving TypeError exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, ionic-framework

So, I am an Ionic and Angular newbie to making mobile apps.  However, I have a basic login form, and a login button which successfully calls a controller.  The controller looks like:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
    .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state) {
        $scope.data = {};

        $scope.login = function() {
            LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password)
                .success(function(data) {
                    // $state.go('tab.dash');
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Login HERE!',
                        template: 'HERE: your credentials!'
                    });
                }).error(function(data) {
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Login failed!',
                        template: 'Please check your credentials!'
                    });
                });
        }
    });
```

This now calls a service which looks like:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
    .service('LoginService', function($http,$q) {
        return {
            loginUser : function(name, pw) {
                console.log('username=' + name + ', password=' + pw);
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var promise = deferred.promise;

                var url = 'https://myURL/myapi/authenticate?username=' + name + '&password=' + pw;
                console.log('url=' + url);

                $http.get(url)
                    .success(function(data) {
                        console.log("success: data=" +data);
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    })
                    .error(function() {
                        console.log("error");
                        deferred.reject("Failed to authenticate");
                    });

                // Return the promise to the controller
                promise.success = function(fn) {
                    promise.then(fn);
                    return promise;
                }
                promise.error = function(fn) {
                    promise.then(null, fn);
                    return promise;
                }

                return promise;
            }
        }
    })
```

The URL I have gets built correctly, it calls the RESTful api correctly.
In the event of a successful login, I get a token id as a single string.
In the event of an unsuccessful login, I get an single line as an error message.

I did read that a GET restful web call expects an array of data.  I can see in the controller.js that:   String data = {};

The real error message I am getting is that .success in the controller is not mapped to getting a String, but an array instead.

If anyone can help me out with whether I can make my data an array, or if I can add a new .success and .error with a single string, that would be great.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here is the exception I got:

```
08-17 11:08:56.412: E/Web Console(6538): TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'success'
08-17 11:08:56.412: E/Web Console(6538):     at Scope.$scope.login (file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js:36:12)
08-17 11:08:56.412: E/Web Console(6538):     at $parseFunctionCall (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21172:18)
08-17 11:08:56.412: E/Web Console(6538):     at IonicModule.config.factory.element.onclick (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:53674:9)
08-17 11:08:56.412: E/Web Console(6538):     at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23228:28)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've way over-complicated your promise handling AFAICT. I'm not even sure what you're trying to do with all those success and error functions. You can just have:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.service('LoginService', function($http,$q) {
    return {
        loginUser : function(name, pw) {
            console.log('username=' + name + ', password=' + pw);

            var url = 'https://myURL/myapi/authenticate?username=' + name + '&password=' + pw;
            console.log('url=' + url);

            return $http.get(url);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: At this time, since I am an AngularJS newbie, I'm not even sure what promises do, or why I need them right now.   I took the sample application from this site:  http://http://devdactic.com/simple-login-example-with-ionic-and-angularjs/   so you might want to ask the author.

Comment: Unfortunately, this fix does not work for me.   Even though I know the URL is correct, the username and password is correct, when it comes back to the controller, I still get an error that the login has failed.  After looking at this "services" code, is there anything I would need to change in the controller code to make this work, so that it says successful login?

Comment: OK, if that code I've supplied above doesn't work, ISTM it must be that the $http call is actually failing in some way. Have you examined the http call in the network tab in the Chrome console to check that it has actually worked as expected? Note that an authentication call like that should probably be a POST, though that is not germane to your issue.

Comment: Oh, there's one other thing. $http calls in angular will return an object which *wraps* the data you are typically interested in. The surrounding object will have information about the http status code and so forth. In your case you are currently doing nothing with the data returned so it doesn't matter, but presuming you are interested in that token, you'll need to consume it via the 'data' property on the response object. This link might help: http://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http

Comment: I just updated my post with my error message that I need to fix.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't make sense. If you're using my code above (simply returning the promise returned by $http.get, then the object returned (the promise) should definitely have a method 'success'. I suggest you assign the object returned to some variable and inspect it to see what you're getting back, i.e.: var promise =LoginService.loginUser(...); console.log(JSON.stringify(promise));